# Como executar meu projeto Phonegap Cordova em um celular com Android 2.3.6?

Tags: android, apache-cordova, ubuntu

Olá estou desenvolvendo um jogo com html5 e javascript como tcc. Estou utilizando o cordova para gerar versões para diferentes plataformas, possuo diversos aparelhos androids para testar o projeto, porém so consigo com o comando "cordova run" executar o projeto nos androids com versão 4.1.2 ou superior o detalhe é que eu precisaria executar o projeto em celulares com android 2.3.6 também.
Alguns pontos interessantes:
- Utilizo linux Ubuntu 15.04 como sistema operacional.
- já pesquisei sobre as versões das plataformas do cordova encontrei alguns comandos mas não funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

A versão mais atual do Cordova não suporta o Android 2.3.6 por ser uma versão que se encontra instalada em menos de 5% dos dispositivos Android atualmente:

> Cordova supports Android 4.0.x (starting with Android API level 14)
>   and higher. As a general rule, Android versions become unsupported by
>   Cordova as they dip below 5% on Google's distribution dashboard.
>   Android versions earlier than API level 10, and the 3.x versions
>   (Honeycomb, API levels 11-13) fall significantly below that 5%
>   threshold.
>   http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

Você pode tentar solucionar isso instalando uma versão mais antiga do Cordova (por exemplo, a versão que tenho instalada atualmente suporta Android API 10 e superior, isto é, inclui a versão 2.3.6):

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova@5.1.1
```

Veja a versão que se encontra instalada atualmente:

```
$ sudo cordova -v
```

Mais detalhes sobre como instalar uma versão específica: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Feito isso, edite o arquivo `config.xml` na pasta raiz do seu projeto e altere a preferência `android-minSdkVersion` para o valor de API mínima suportada pela versão do Cordova baixada. Em outras palavras, troque esta linha:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
```

por esta:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="10" />
```

Comment: Ok, fiz a instalação de uma versão mais antiga. Mas e agora como faço para adicionar a versão mais antiga ao projeto que eu tenho?

Comment: Complementei a resposta.